# Prove that all solutions to the equation x² = x +1 are irrational

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I'm pretty new to discrete mathematics and I'm having a hard time understanding how to solve some problems--this one in particular.

Any help would be greatly appreciated even if it's just something to help me get started. Thanks.

Comment: I reckon you can start from the basics: set $x=\frac{p}{q}$ with $p,q$ integers and try to find a contradiction.

Comment: Well, this is just the quadratic equation. You can solve it, and show that neither solution is rational.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By the [Rational Root Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem), the only possible rational solutions are $-1, +1$, which are promptly seem not to be solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Do you know that for a rational root $p/q$ of a polynomial $P(x)=a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_1x+a_0$ with integer coefficients

- $p$ must divide $a_0$, and
- $q$ must divide $a_n$ ?

Answer (score 1):

Any solution of $x^2=x+1$ is a solution of $x=1+\frac{1}{x}$, hence a number with an infinite [continued fraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction) representation, hence an irrational number.

Comment: Is this really valid? I mean $x^2 = +2x -1$ is a solution if $x = 2-1/x$ which also is infinite continued fraction but has two integer solutions.

Comment: @mathreadler: Any solution of $x=\color{red}{n}\color{blue}{+}\frac{\color{purple}{1}}{x}$ does the job, provided that $n\in\mathbb{N}^+$, since that gives $x=[n;,n,n,\ldots]$ or $x=-1/[n;,n,n,n,\ldots]$.

Comment: So the positivity of the one over the $x$ is important, you say?

Comment: @mathreadler: well, $x=2-\frac{1}{x}$ does not lead for sure to a "canonical" continued fraction, it leads to $x = 2-\frac{1}{2-\frac{1}{2-\ldots}}$, but that has little to do with the extended Euclidean algorithm.